# assigning geom_hline value based on filtered data, and doing this as part of the same code chunk?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, geom-hline

I'm trying assign geom_hline based on filtered data and selection of value from one column, but doing this all within the same code chunk. I am not sure what the best way is go about it - any help would be much appreciated.

sample data:

```
structure(list(sample_name = c("control1", "control2", "S01", 
"S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", "S07", "S08"), estimate = c(1.703, 
5.553, 4.851, 5.257, 4.573, 3.278, 1.687, 3.628, 1.877, 5.826
), std.error = c(1.767, 2.382, 1.641, 1.062, 1.133, 1.477, 0.978, 
0.611, 1.893, 0.78), upper_limit_value = c(5.166, 10.223, 8.067, 
7.339, 6.795, 6.173, 3.605, 4.825, 5.586, 7.355), lower_limit_value = c(-1.761, 
0.884, 1.635, 3.175, 2.352, 0.384, -0.231, 2.431, -1.833, 4.298
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

```
df%>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(???)
```

within the geom_hline() part, is there a way to define what the y-intercept should be based on filtered data - almost like a side assignment?

something along the lines of

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = df %>% filter(sample_name="control1") %>% select("upper_limit_value"))) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = df %>% filter(sample_name="control1") %>% select("lower_limit_value")))
```

In this case, there's only one row of filtered data for sample_name="control1", and I'm trying to use the value under the "upper_limit_value " column (and "lower_limit_value " value as a separate geom_hline).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to subset the data *in the `data` argument*:

```
geom_hline(data = df %>% filter(sample_name == "control") %>% select(upper_limit_value),
           mapping = aes(yintercept = upper_limit_value))
```

The complete code would then become the following.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(data = df %>% filter(sample_name == "control") %>% select(upper_limit_value),
             mapping = aes(yintercept = upper_limit_value))
```

(I don't believe there's need to `select(upper_limit_value)` but without test data it's not easy to say.)

Another option is to use `pull` in the question's code, not `select`. The difference is that `select` returns a data set with those columns and `pull` returns the columns values.

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = df %>% filter(sample_name == "control") %>% pull(upper_limit_value)))
```

---

## Edit

The data transformation I am refering to above is

```
df$sample_name[df$sample_name == "control2"] <- "control"
```

Then the `filter` in `geom_hline` returns a data set with 1 row.

After [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635063/assigning-geom-hline-value-based-on-filtered-data-and-doing-this-as-part-of-the/64635175?noredirect=1#comment114285282_64635175) I have tested the code with the posted data (but after changing `"control2"` to `"control"`) and everything works as expected.

I would also suggest that the initial pipe of `df` into `ggplot` is not needed, since no transformations are to be applied to the data set.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = df %>% filter(sample_name == "control") %>% pull(upper_limit_value)))
```

Comment: thanks! is there a reason that for the second option
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = df %>% filter(sample_name == "control") %>% pull(upper_limit_value))) why the "df" can't just be "."??
I get the following error "Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): yintercept = `%>%`(...). 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?"

Comment: @dnmc Try replacing the df name with a dot and see. Like I said, without data I couldn't test the code. Oh, now I saw the question edited with code. Be right back.

Comment: @dnmc The df has one value `"control1"` and another `"control"` but no `"control"`, after filtering it's a zero rows tibble.

Comment: ah - sorry for mixup, i had changed some column names before posting the sample data set. If i run the following
df %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = . %>% filter(sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value)))
I get 
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): yintercept = . %>% filter(sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value). 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm piping into ggplot because there are other things I'm planning to do with the larger data set involving transformation :)

Comment: @dnmc The error probably means that `upper_limit_value` only exists in `stackover_df`, not in `df`.

Comment: pardon the typo. the only difference between what works and what doesn't was whether it's yintercept = df %>% (works) OR yintercept = . %>% (doesn't work)

just trying to get a better understanding of why the former works but not the latter. thanks again for your help!
this works df %>% ggplot(., aes(x=sample_name, y=estimate, group=sample_name, color=sample_name))+ geom_point() + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = df %>% filter(sample_name == "control1") %>% pull(upper_limit_value)))